# In Pandas, how to plot this dataframe from excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot

I can't for the love of me solve this. It must be very simple but I can't.

I'm importing an excel (xlsx) to pandas, with this shape:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn1Re.png

What I want is something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCInN.png

The code I'm using to import it is this:

```
Data_excel = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
```

But I don't know how to continue, it never lets me plot what I want and I don't know how to set the x and y values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missed the `'` before and after the filename.

Your code should be something like this:

```
Data_excel = pd.read_excel("excel_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a mistake when changing the name of the file for the post. I was successful in importing the dataframe but I can't figure out how to arrange it to plot what I want.

Comment: What type of data you're dealing with? Because if you want to plot something like timeseries, you must have data for x axis and y axis. In your example I can only imagine 2 bar plots, not line plots.

Comment: I want to plot for each day, all the values of the Tests for that day, connecting the values from day 1 to day 2 for the same Test (row). I think I would have this problem even if I later add more days (columns)